# Connect Bot built with Microsoft Bot Framework to other connectors/Channels too

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

I have built a bot using Microsoft bot framework. Now I want to connect it to channels which are not supported by the Microsoft bot connector. However, I need to build an interface (or a substitute for bot connector) to connect to those channels. But as I am using Bot framework SDK (NodeJs), I need the best approach to expose the endpoint of my bot engine to other connectors/channels.

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Framework has a mechanism specifically for this scenario, called Direct Line. Essentially, you build the UI interface yourself, but use the Direct Line API to forward events to/from the Bot Connector. You can use the [Direct Line REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts), or find an npm package where someone has taken care of the underlying plumbing for you, as in the [botframework-directline.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine) package. Microsoft has some [node.js BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine) on their GitHub site too.

> Note: The typical way to get the best help on SO is to post code of
>   what you've tried and that gives people a better idea of how to help.
>   I understand you don't know where to start, so that doesn't help much,
>   but maybe it will explain why you're getting Close flags.

Comment: I have already gone through the Direct Line API, but I want direct access to my bot engine instead of via MS bot connector, is it possible?

Comment: While you might be able to send messages, it's just a REST endpoint, it could be challenging. You'd encounter problems receiving chatbot responses because Bot Builder API methods communicate directly with the Bot Connector. Theoretically, you might set the service URL to your own server, but then you'd need to write code that acts like the Bot Connector, handling IDs, routing, various IActivity types, and all the tasks associated with architectural aspects of a distributed computing platform. Sounds like the effort won't pay for itself unless you're building a custom bot platform.

Comment: Exactly! the complication here is, the bot sends a response to the bot connector instead of the request URL. Anyways I was just wondering if there is any POC already built. Or something which could point me in a correct direction.